# Error generated by LastPage when using pageref

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing

I have no idea why I get the following error when I try to reference `(refer to table~\ref{trparam} on page~\pageref{\textbf{trparam}}`.

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.

<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.179 ...param} on page~\pageref{\textbf{trparam}}
                                                  )
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\reserved@a ->\def \reserved@a 
                               *{\@pagerefstar }\reserved@a 
l.179 ...param} on page~\pageref{\textbf{trparam}}
                                                  )
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please provide a MSE (minimal working example) that displays this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to print the page number in **bold**, you should use

```
Refer to Table~\ref{tab:table} on page~\textbf{\pageref{tab:table}}.
```

where `\textbf` is applied not to the label being referenced, but the setting of the retrieved `\pageref`.